# Python Eel cant be installed

Tags: python, eel

I was trying to install eel using pip install eel but I get an error of

```
C:\Users\USER>pip install eel
Collecting eel
  Using cached Eel-0.7.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-aa7ptb\eel\setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        long_description=open('README.md', encoding='utf-8').readlines()[1],
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-aa7ptb\eel\
```

I tried using pip install --upgrade setuptools but still doesnt work.

using python 2.7

Comment: The package obviously requires Python 3.

Comment: This means that Eel only supports Python 3

Answer (score 1):

The `open` function in Python 2.7 has a different signature and especially no keyword argument called `encoding`, as you can read from the error message.

Eel seems to no support Python 2.7 (you should go with Python 3 anyways ;)

`open` in Python 2.7: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

`open` in Python 3.6: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open